# Updating Bike to Road bike

Tags: road-bike, upgrades

I have a really old bike that hasn't been ridden in dozens of years. Now tho, I want to update it to road bike. It is in really bad condition and because I'm from Eastern Europe, my budget is low. What parts do I need to change/add/remove? Size of frame is 56cm/22".

[image]

Comment: Yeah, the bike in the picture is a single-speed unit with coaster brakes.  A minimal "road bike" would have at least a rear derailer or a multi-speed hub.  Your best bet is to find another used bike that is closer to what you need, as fixing up this one is not worth the money.

Comment: Plug in some slick tyres, and watch on road velocity increase!

Answer (score 4):

The only easily replaced part are the tires. The rims look too wide to fit actual road racing tires, but you can probably find something with lower rolling resistance.

Other than that, this is not a road bike in the usual English sense of the word and can be turned into one only by replacing everything. Consider getting a suitable used bike instead.

Comment: -1: Explain the last statement, otherwise is merely an opinion. Happy to remove down vote if you do.

Comment: @mattnz I take it to mean the difference between a road bike intended for riding on the road to go places, vs a road bike for going fast on the road in a race.

Answer (score 2):

Check the perishable parts and replace with new if required.  That's tyres, tubes, brake blocks.

You should find and fit some rear brakes as well - I see mounts but no arms, and the brake outer appears to be cut just in front of the seat tube.

Otherwise grease and repack the wheel bearings if they need it, and clean and oil the chain.

For comfort and keeping clean, I'd suggest keeping the mudguards/fenders too.

Comment: This is not a road bike in the usual sense of the word, and will not be turned into one. Regarding the rear brake, there is a coaster brake. The reaction arm is visible behind the chain.

Comment: @ojs Good spotting - I missed that.  This shows that its already a bitser bike.